# Angular :: Link to parent 'router-outlet' from a nested outlet

Tags: angular, routes

I have a component within a nested router-outlet, but would like to create a link to a route that is in the parent's router-outlet. I am not sure what code you guys would want to see for me to explain this?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to do it from the template (maybe seeing this answer someone could show me the way to do it from the template), but I was able to make it work by navigating programmatically like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['../../account-view/' + id], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can point to anywhere in your app with `routerLink` regardless of where you are. It is just the matter of how you set the route. If you start the route with `/` it means from base (don't forget to set the base in your HTML).

If you use `./` it is relative to where you are.

So let's assume you have two main routes, **admin** and **frontpages**, which have their own modules. Inside admin there is a users route and inside frontpage there is about route. You can have a link to admin from about like this:

```
<a routerLink="/admin/users">Admin</a>
```

I created [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes-zex4xf) for you to checkout.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this makes sense, but for some reason is not working for me. I have a submodule (teachers) which then houses the  router-outlet 'sub'. I thought from within the 'sub' outlet I could navigate to another page in the teachers module by doing some combination of '../account-view' or './account-view' but it throws errors and the error points to the fact that it is still trying to find the route from within the sub outlet.

Comment: Correction, using absolute path does work, but what I am trying to do is a relative path within a module because the component that I am using within the sub outlet is used in other modules.

Comment: I am lost, components? if you use string as routes wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: I have a teacher module ('/teacher') with its own router. I then have a sub-router-outlet within the module. From this nested view, I am calling a global component which I would like to be able to link to a relative path of the 'teacher' module.

Comment: you can use `../../` approach if you want to go up the route hierarchy

Comment: I tried that, but it seems like that never gets me out of the sub-outlet's references. for example, a link like this: `routerLink="../../teacher/account-view/1"` ends up looking like this: `<a _ngcontent-c13="" href="/teacher/account-view/3/(sub:colleagues)" routerlink="../../teacher/account-view/1" ng-reflect-router-link="../../teacher/account-view/1">`

I would like it to look like `/teacher/account-view/1`

Comment: In that case you might have to change your route configuration have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011)